# Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException when connecting to a Fabric datawarehouse trough a COM DLL

Tags: vba, vb.net, microsoft-data-sqlclient

I have created a COM-DLL to connect to a Fabric datawarehouse.
Using the Microsoft.Data.SqlClient Nuget library.

When using the DLL from antother VStudio Project works fine.
But when I'm using the DLL from EXCEL VBA Then it fails.

This is Code from my DLL

```
Imports Microsoft.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Program
    Public Sub New()

    End Sub

    Public Function TestNy() As Boolean '(ByVal args As String()) As Boolean
        TestNy = True
        Try
            Dim builder As SqlConnectionStringBuilder = New SqlConnectionStringBuilder()
            builder.DataSource = "TEST.datawarehouse.pbidedicated.windows.net,1433"
            builder.UserID = "TEST@aTEST.no"
            builder.Password = "BIGSECRET"
            builder.InitialCatalog = "PA_VNXT_WH_200"
            builder.Authentication = SqlAuthenticationMethod.ActiveDirectoryPassword
            builder.Encrypt = False
            builder.TrustServerCertificate = True
            builder.MultiSubnetFailover = True

            Using connection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString)

                connection.Open() 'THIS IS THE LINE THAT FAILS

                Dim sql As String = "SELECT name, collation_name FROM sys.databases"

                Using command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sql, connection)

                    Using reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()

                        While reader.Read()
                            'Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", reader.GetString(0), reader.GetString(1))
                        End While
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using

        Catch e As SqlException


            MsgBox(e.ToString())
        End Try


    End Function
End Class`
```

If I create a simple console .exe project and calls my very simple dll.
I can connect with no error

EXE file that works fine

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports PowerAnalyze_XL.Program
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim b As New PowerAnalyze_XL.Program
        If b.TestNy() Then
        End If
    End Sub

End Module
```

But if i try to connect via VBA And a Excel "macro" it fails
excel

```
`Sub koko()
 Dim s() As String
 
    Set b = CreateObject("PowerAnalyze_XL.Program")
    If b.TestNy() Then '(s) Then
    End If
   
End Sub`
```

Debugging isolates the  exception to the line
connection.Open()

The error i got back is:

```
---------------------------
PowerAnalyze_XL
---------------------------
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)

   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

   at System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)

   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)

   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Http.HttpManager.<ExecuteAsync>d__15.MoveNext()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Http.HttpManagerWithRetry.<SendRequestAsync>d__7.MoveNext()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Http.HttpManagerWithRetry.<SendGetAsync>d__2.MoveNext()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.OAuth2.OAuth2Client.<ExecuteRequestAsync>d__12`1.MoveNext()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.OAuth2.OAuth2Client.<DiscoverAadInstanceAsync>d__9.MoveNext()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Instance.Discovery.NetworkMetadataProvider.<SendInstanceDiscoveryRequestAsync>d__7.MoveNext()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Instance.Discovery.NetworkMetadataProvider.<FetchAllDiscoveryMetadataAsync>d__6.MoveNext()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Instance.Discovery.NetworkMetadataProvider.<GetMetadataAsync>d__4.MoveNext()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Instance.Discovery.InstanceDiscoveryManager.<FetchNetworkMetadataOrFallbackAsync>d__10.MoveNext()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Instance.Discovery.InstanceDiscoveryManager.<GetMetadataEntryAsync>d__9.MoveNext()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Instance.AuthorityManager.<RunInstanceDiscoveryAndValidationAsync>d__12.MoveNext()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.UsernamePasswordRequest.<ExecuteAsync>d__5.MoveNext()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.RequestBase.<RunAsync>d__12.MoveNext()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.ApiConfig.Executors.PublicClientExecutor.<ExecuteAsync>d__5.MoveNext()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.ActiveDirectoryAuthenticationProvider.<AcquireTokenAsync>d__21.MoveNext()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.<>c__DisplayClass159_1.<<GetFedAuthToken>b__3>d.MoveNext()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()

   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.GetFedAuthToken(SqlFedAuthInfo fedAuthInfo)

   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.GetFedAuthToken(SqlFedAuthInfo fedAuthInfo)

   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OnFedAuthInfo(SqlFedAuthInfo fedAuthInfo)

   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)

   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)

   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK)

   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover, Boolean isFirstTransparentAttempt, Boolean disableTnir)

   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)

   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)

   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, ServerCertificateValidationCallback serverCallback, ClientCertificateRetrievalCallback clientCallback, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, SqlClientOriginalNetworkAddressInfo originalNetworkAddressInfo, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling)

   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)

   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)

   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)

   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)

   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)

   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)

   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)

   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)

   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)

   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)

   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open(SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)

   at PowerAnalyze_XL.Program.TestNy() in C:\PROSJEKTER\PowerAnalyze_XL\CommonStuff.vb:line 27

ClientConnectionId:660969af-d2ef-49be-a7cc-c8eb26eaefb7

ClientConnectionId before routing:69d9c378-9651-4e35-824f-2440265f7195

Routing Destination:b196817a7d654fa6b531943f71616da4.pbidedicated.windows.net\3VS2PBU2555UJL7CN7DH7VID2Q-XB4C354RFVMUVKHPRHWXIEEYUM-dw,1433
```

I suspect that the problem are related to the fact that it is EXCEL.EXE that are the process calling the COM DLL.
I've been mocking around in excel.exe.config but to no luck.

After spending "a lifetime" with the reliable System.Data.SqlClient on my apps this is really annoying. And I have run out of ideas.

I do appreciate any input.

Comment: "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" has nothing to do with COM and nothing to do with Excel, it's a (classic) network connection error.

Comment: @SimonMourier  Tanks for input. True that. But the error only comes when calling COM DLL fom Excel.exe. I hva also tried different excel versions x86 /x64 etc.. but to no luck.

Comment: It's a networking error, that can be due to many causes, maybe your excel.exe has a firewall rule or something like that, but it's probably specific to your machine/setup

Comment: and if you add a public function such as  Public MyHello() as string and return "hello world", does that work from VBA? And you of course don't use ANY CPU but set/force the project to the same bit size as Excel is running as.